# Как реализовать вертикальную прокрутку на веб-сайте через меню?

Tags: jquery

Ребятки, такой вопрос! Помогите найти или реализовать вертикальный скролл слева как на примере http://rs-3d.com/. Очень надо, выручайте) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Все это так или иначе решается плагином для [вертикальной прокрутки](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/vertical-scroller). Их там есть вроде штук 5 уже написанных.

Конкретно [вот этот(FSVS) порадовал минимализмом и ясностью](http://luke.sno.wden.co.uk/full-screen-vertical-scroll).

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // The HTML tag must have a class of fsvs
    var fsvs = $.fn.fsvs({
        speed : 1000
    });
});
```

Все.

Comment: Спасибо огромное друг)

Answer (score 0):

Таких плагинов куча. Например, вот один из них
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html